# Postgresql with EF6 creation of ddex is failed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, postgresql, orm

I'm trying to to work with Entity Framework 6, and connect it to a Postgresql
database.

I'm using npgsql.Entityframework, but get an error when creating the ddex file.
[image]

Can someone knows why?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more data to the question, a printscreen or error info?

Comment: If you are using npgsql.Entityframework so it for a postgresql wright?

Comment: yeah i am using postgresql

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @saranhya narakedamilli Does it help you?

Comment: sorry this is first time i am asking a question in stack overflow probably i didn't explain properly. solution helped me a lot. Thanks a lot @Nir Schwartz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install **Npgsql**, to work between **Entity Framework** to **PostgreSql**:

1. Download and install the **Setup_NpgsqlDdexProvider.exe** from https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases.
2. Open Visual-Studio, click on the tab: **TOOLS -> Setup Npgsql DbProviderFactories**.
   A window will open, you need to click OK.

[image]

3. **Close Visual-Studio** and open as **administrator** the two **machine.config** files of .NET with notepad.

There are two file that we need to edit, you can find the file at the paths:

> - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
> - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Add the flowing element to the files:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
         invariant="Npgsql"
         description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
         type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"
         support="FF" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

4. Reopen Visual-Studio at the wanted project.
5. Install Entity Framework through Nuget.
6. Open the **Package Manager Console** and insert the commend:

   ```
   Install-Package EntityFramework6.Npgsql
   ```

Check that the wanted DLL are references, like so:

[image]

If not add the DLL manually. The sopose to be at the paths:

> - C:\Users\YOURCOMPUTERNAME\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PostgreSqlVsEfwDemo\packages\Npgsql.3.0.5\lib\net45\Npgsql.dll
> - C:\Users\ YOURCOMPUTERNAME\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PostgreSqlVsEfwDemo\packages\EntityFramework6.Npgsql.3.0.5\lib\net45\EntityFramework6.Npgsql.dll

7. Open the App.config\Web.config and add two elements:

   - The provider element at entityFramework -> providers. as so:
   - The provider element at DbProviderFactories. as so:

     ```
     <system.data>
     <DbProviderFactories>
       <remove invariant="Npgsql" />

       <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
     </DbProviderFactories>
     ```

If the `<system.data>` element isn't exist, add it all.

8. Now lets add **Entity Data Model** like so:

   - Select "EF Designer from database"

[image]

- Click on "New Connection"

[image]

- Choose the "PostgreSQL Database" as the Data source:
  [image]
- Filled the fields:

  - HOST
  - USERNAME
  - PASSWORD
  - PORT
  - DATABASE (fill this field last.)

[image]

9. Click on "Test Connection" to see if it works.
10. Continue with Entity Framework as regular.

Hope it's help you.

[This document](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html) of Npgsql Docs really helped me, but still have problems.